# Share the passport authentication between http and websocket parts of express.io app

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, passport.js, express.io

I have the **passport** HTTP authentication:

```
var express = require('express.io');
var passport = require('passport');
var expressSession = require('express-session');

var app = express().http().io();
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(expressSession({ secret: 'someSecretWord' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

```js
router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {
  successRedirect: "/index"
}));

//It works fine like this:
router.get("/index", authMiddleware.isAuthenticatedUser, function (req, res) {
    res.render("index");
});

//But doesn't affect WebSocket, so this won't work:
app.io.route('getMessage', authMiddleware.isAuthenticatedUser, function (req) {
  controller.getMessage(req).then(function (message) {
    req.io.respond(message);
  });
});
```

What is the best way to **share** the authentication between HTTP and WebSocket requests?

Comment: The solution is probably similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47526793/how-to-use-subscriptions-transport-ws-with-passport-and-express-session/53199673#53199673